# Split a view into two parts to display separately

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I have a string within a custom view that is being displayed on screen. The trouble is, it needs to be truncated as there is not enough horizontal space to fit in. I want to know if it is possible to do this wacky idea of displaying the view with its text as much as possible, then going to the next line and displaying the rest of the view with the remaining text.

So essentially, display for ex, half the view then display the other half below. Is there a way to display subsections of a view?

Comment: Why don't you just use a multi-line label to display the string? I don't understand why you want to split the view.

Comment: I am unable to use a label and would like to know if this specific case is possible for another reason. This is a toy example of what I am supposed to do

Comment: I'm not sure about displaying subsections of a view, but you can create an image of the view, and then create sub-images with CGImageCreateWithImageInRect.

Comment: Is there any way to actually just find out what text was shown on screen and which substring was truncated? That way I could just make another view with the text that was not shown by the first one due to being cut off

Comment: How are you showing the text on the screen? You said you can't use a label, so are you just drawing the text into a view?

Comment: Yes thats how its being done right now. I just want a way to know how much of the text was there based on maybe width available and text size/font so i can then have another view with the remaining text elsewhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62840/discussion-between-john-baum-and-rdelmar).

Answer (score 0):

One way to determine where the line breaks fall would be to put the string into a UILabel (not to be displayed) with the same font as your view and use the sizeThatFits: method to get the display width of the text. If that’s less than your view width, then you’re good to go, otherwise remove a character (or word if you don’t want to break mid-word) from the end of the string and repeat until it’s small enough to fit. Render that string and repeat with the rest of the original string.

If strings are likely to span many lines, that could get inefficient, so you might want to make sure that you don’t start with too many characters in the string you’re testing the display width of (truncate to a reasonable number based on the view width), or build up your string, rather than truncating from the end.

Might also need to adjust the edge insets on the UILabel to match how you’re rendering the text.

Answer (score 0):

This code should get you close to what you want. I enumerate the text by word, and check whether the length of each substring will fit in the view. Once I find that substring, I calculate what the rest of the string is, adjust the height of the view to be the height of this one line of text, and stop the enumeration. I tested this on a view that was setup to be 178w x 140h in the storyboard.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "RDView.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet RDView *firstLineView; // the view we're drawing the text into
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightCon; // height constraint for the view we're drawing the first line into
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *firstLine;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *restOfLine;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSDictionary *attribs;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self drawFirstLineOfString:@"This is my pretty long string with extra words" withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]];
}

-(void)drawFirstLineOfString:(NSString *) text withFont:(UIFont *) font {
    self.attribs = @{NSFontAttributeName:font};
    __block NSString *lastFragment;
    [text enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, text.length) options:NSStringEnumerationByWords usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString *textFragment = [text substringToIndex:(substringRange.location + substringRange.length)];
        CGRect textRect = [textFragment boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX ,CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:self.attribs context:nil];
        if (textRect.size.width >= self.firstLineView.bounds.size.width - 2) { // the -2 is for padding at either end. The string will bedrawn starting at x=1
            self.firstLine = lastFragment;
            self.restOfLine = [text substringFromIndex:substringRange.location];
            self.heightCon.constant = textRect.size.height; // adjust the height of the view to the height of the text
            *stop = YES;
        }
        lastFragment = textFragment;
    }];

    NSLog(@"self.text is:%@",self.firstLine);
    NSLog(@"rest of line is:%@", self.restOfLine);
    self.firstLineView.firstLine = self.firstLine;
    self.firstLineView.attributes = self.attribs;
}
```

The custom view has the two properties that I set in the last two lines above, and this code in the .m,

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if (self.firstLine) {
        [self.firstLine drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(1,0) withAttributes:self.attributes];
    }
}
```